# AWS EC2: ubuntu 22.04,unable to to update

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-22.04

EC2: ubuntu 22.04,unable to to update

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-81-55:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
```

I am not able to update the repos.

[image]

Comment: does the instance have public access?

Comment: ping google.com works